# Add a sheet into existing excel file

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to add a sheet to existing excel file. How can I do that? I am working on one selenium project and I want to add all of my automation result sheets into single excel file. Right now I am able to create new excel file for each sheet.

Comment: If this needs a non-VBA answer then you should specify this.

Comment: Consider adding the tag "apache-poi" to your question, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Apache POI` from Java:

To open an existing sheet or to create a new sheet respectively:

```
final File file = "/tmp/sheet.xls";
final HSSFWorkbook workbook;
if (file.exists() == false) {
  System.out.println("Creating a new workbook '" + file + "'");
  workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
} else {
  System.out.println("Appending to existing workbook '" + file + "'");
  final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
  try {
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
  } finally {
    is.close();
  }
}
```

To check whether a sheet exists in order to create a unique sheet name, you could use something like this:

```
int sheetIndex = 1;
while (workbook.getSheet("Sheet " + sheetIndex) != null) {
  sheetIndex++;
}
```

then you can add a sheet by calling `createSheet`:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet " + sheetIndex);
```

In this case the sheet names are "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", etc.

Answer (score 2):

From VBA, with the proper workbook activated:

```
Sheets.Add
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Worksheets.Add
```

(when automating, it is best to be specific)

You need to maintain a reference to this new worksheet. In VBA this would be

```
Set wsRef = Worksheets.Add
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention that I am coding in JAVA and so far I am calling following function to write a file-      
       File outFile = new File(sPath);
     HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
     HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(iSheet);
      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
     int xRows = xData.length;
     int xCols = xData[0].length;
     for(int i =0;i<xRows;i++)
     {
      HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
      for(int j=0;j<xCols;j++)
      {
     }//for i
    }//xlwrite