# Adding a sheet in an existing excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have tried in various ways to add an Excel spreadsheet. But the problem is always the same.

I tried the codes proposed here,

- [Add a sheet into existing excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383955/add-a-sheet-into-existing-excel-file)
- [Creating New Sheet In Existing Excel Workbook Using Apache POI for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436243/creating-new-sheet-in-existing-excel-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java)

The problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BOFRecord cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.hssf.record.TabIdRecord
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.fixTabIdRecord(InternalWorkbook.java:792)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.checkSheets(InternalWorkbook.java:742)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.setSheetName(InternalWorkbook.java:579)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:748)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:101)
    at ReadTry.main(ReadTry.java:28)
```

Comment: can you paste your code - what are the details of the xl file ? do you start from an empty xl or you already have tabs ?

Comment: provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get quick answer

Comment: @ Frederic Henri   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("C:/Users/try/NewExcelFile.xls"));
  Sheet s = wb.createSheet();

  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/try/NewExcelFile222.xls");
 
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();

Answer (score 0):

Same code works for me

```
public class Modify {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File f=new File("d:/temp/wb.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
    wb.createSheet("sheet2");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/temp/wb1.xls");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
  }
}
```

I used `poi-3.9-20121203.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar`

Comment: In my case this code works only if the input file (d:/temp/wb.xls ) is empty

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: I would like a way to make it work, when the sheet contains data

Comment: still I dont understand, which sheet contains data. when you add new sheet, it will become fresh right

Comment: this file contains data: C:/Users/try/NewExcelFile.xls. The sheet has about 500 rows. I'm trying to copy this sheet in another file xls files.This will have more sheets